# Equivalent condition to weakly Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

In tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology", it says that a space $X$ is weakly Hausdorff if and only if for every compact Hausdorff space $K$, every continuous map $f: K\to X$ is proper. (See Proposition 7.9.1.) I know how to prove the "only if" direction. But how can I prove the converse direction?

Tom Dieck uses the following definitions:
A space $X$ is weakly Hausdorff if for any compact Hausdorff space $K$ and any continuous map $f:K\to X$, the image $f(K)\subset X$ is closed, and a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ is proper if it is closed and its fibres $f^{-1}(y)\subset X$, $y\in Y$ are compact.

Comment: What is Dieck's *definition* of weakly Hausdorff and proper?

Comment: I have just noticed that he defines "proper" in a different way I was used to. He says a space X is weakly Hausdorff if for any compact Hausdorff space K and any continuous map `f:K\to X`, the image `f(K)` is closed, and a continuous map is proper if it is closed and its fibres are compact. Now, it's clear. Thank you!

Comment: Even if the question  has been answered now, you should add all relevant information (here: the definitions of *weakly Hausdorff*  and *proper*) to your question. Comments are not the right place to do that.

Comment: I have added the definitions, sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Rightarrow$: If $X$ is weakly Hausdorff, let $f: K \to X$ be continuous where $K$ is compact Hausdorff; we have to show it's proper. If $C \subseteq K$ is closed, $C$ is compact Hausdorff too, and so we apply weakly Hausdorff to $f|C$ to conclude that $f[C]$ is closed in $X$, so $f$ is a closed map. And if $x \in X$ then $\{x\}$ is closed (weakly Hausdorff implies $T_1$ because a one point space is compact Hausdorff trivially) and so $f^{-1}[\{x\}]$ is closed in $K$ by continuity and hence compact. So, in all, $f$ is proper (in the definition as given in the comments).

$\Leftarrow$: This is trivial: if $f:K \to X$ is continuous it's proper and so a closed map and in particular $f[K]$ is closed in $X$ (as $K$ is closed in $K$).